# ReactJS - Parent Get PropTypes of Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

im trying to get the Child PropTypes from the parent,

but somehow nothing is working

**my Child Component:**

```
    const EntityCardComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div style={props.style} onClick={props.onClick} className={`card-background img-fluid ${props.className} ${props.isSelected ? 'glow-effect' : ''}`}>
            <div className="h-10">
                <img className='img-fluid w-20' alt="" src={require('../../../resources/img/frame/CircleFrame.png')} />
            </div>
            <div className="h-80">
                <img className='img-fluid' alt="" src={require(`../../../resources/img/${props.entityType}/${props.entity.characterEntity.avatar}.png`)} />
            </div>
            <div className="h-10">
                <hr className="style14" />
                <h5 className="text-center battle-shonen-header-text">{props.entity.characterEntity.name}</h5>
                <hr className="style14" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

EntityCardComponent.propTypes = {
    isSelected: PropTypes.bool,
    entity: PropTypes.object,
    entityType: PropTypes.string
};

EntityCardComponent.defaultProps = {
    isSelected: false
};
```

and i would like to access the propTypes over my Parent Component, i tryed like so:

```
    const testClick = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    }

   {availablePlayer.map((item, index) => 
   <EntityCardComponent key={index} className={'card-background col-md-2 img-fluid mr-2 ml-2 p-0 p-3'} isSelected={false} entity={item} entityType={'character'} onClick={(e) => testClick(e)}/>
```

obv. i also tryed different methods but the only thing i can expose is the "css" data ..

can someone help me out here pls ? :X

Comment: What do you mean by trying to "access the propTypes over my Parent Component"? Are you talking about the `testClick` and the `console.log(e)` statement?

Comment: i want to be able to modify the propTypes over my parent but before trying to modify them, i try to access them onClick

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "modifying the propTypes" - `propTypes` are there for a reason to let you know what type of `props` are expected, you should not be attempting to change those dynamically - these are for your and your colleagues to know what type of `props` this component takes. Unless I am not understanding what you're asking, you might be mixing things up.

Comment: Well actualy i get what you mean and i missUsed the propTypes x)